When sending multiple images using multer, only the first image is being processed. How can I fix this?
I am developing an image upload feature in my Node.js application using multer for handling file uploads. When I send multiple images at once through Postman, only the first image is processed correctly in req.files, while the subsequent images appear as null in req.body. However, if I upload the images one by one, they are received without any issues.
this is my upload code
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

// Configure storage (disk storage in this case)
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${uniqueSuffix}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});

// Setup multer upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 }, // 5 MB limit
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
    const extname = fileTypes.test(
      path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
    );
    const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb(new Error("Only images and PDF files are allowed!"));
  },
}).fields([
  { name: "businessCertificate", maxCount: 1 },
  { name: "hkidCard", maxCount: 1 },
  { name: "mainImage", maxCount: 1 },
]);

module.exports = upload;

this is how I am sending my api

router.put(
  "/:id",
  authMiddleware.authenticate.bind(authMiddleware),
  upload,
  (req, res) => {
    if (req.files) {
      console.log("Files received:", req.files);
    }

    console.log("Request body:", req.body);
  }
);

here is my postman query

Here is my output
Files received: [Object: null prototype] {
  businessCertificate: [
    {
      fieldname: 'businessCertificate',
      originalname: 'Screenshot 2024-09-05 002708.png',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      destination: 'uploads/',
      filename: 'businessCertificate-1729668535864-740051976.png',
      path: 'uploads\\businessCertificate-1729668535864-740051976.png',
      size: 35854
    }
  ]
}
Request body: [Object: null prototype] { mainImage: '', hkidCard: '' }



Share the post man screenshot

It should be upload.array(fieldName, maxCount) in PUT route args, check docs.

I think array is for when I am sending multiple files in one parameter. But when I am sending three different parameters do I need to use array?

what does authMiddleware.authenticate.bind(authMiddleware) do, did you try removing it. did you try making request with other client (curl, browser etc)

authMiddleware.authenticate.bind(authMiddleware) is for check my token. I tried removing it but still same issue

did you try sending files with something other than postman

try some dummy html form, it's most probably postman issue: multer fields array returned only first file #1269
